# Mysql find max column value based on array list

Tags: mysql

Hi i have following mysql table

```
id  item_name user_id wishlist item_url id_category cost
30     kiko    76        1                 70         10
31     test1   76        1                 70         20
32     test12  76        1                 68,67      30
```

How can i get max cost item. Which means i need max cost item based on category id.[image]

My attempt of using `SELECT MAX(cost),id FROM item_tbl WHERE (FIND_IN_SET('68','70,68,67'))` not return a correct output thought it gives `max(cost)` of 30. Thanks

Comment: What's the correct output you want?

Comment: What result would you expect ? THe max cost of your list is indeed 30, so the query seems to give the correct answer.

Comment: i need category_id as output, but it return me wrong category_id though i get correct max(cost) value

Comment: why is id_category containing two values? You should better create a new table to store this information

Answer (score 1):

This might give you the desired output.

```
SELECT ID_CATEGORY, MAX(COST) FROM ITEM_TBL
GROUP BY ID_CATEGORY;
```

Comment: where is category id?

Comment: there is no 'category id' in your table as well

Comment: I assume id_category is category id in your table.